# What type of connector does this flow-meter use?

Tags: connector

I bought the following flow sensor:

https://www.adafruit.com/product/828

[image]

[image]

It generates pulses for each revolution. Now I connected it to Arduino via Dupont connectors. I want to make a proper PCB for my project. Please help me find the connector type.

Comment: What does the datasheet say? Can you provide a link to that datasheet?

Comment: The datasheet doesn't give information about the connector. Here is link to the page where I bought it.

https://www.adafruit.com/product/828

Comment: Can you tell us which connector on the Arduino you plugged it into?

Comment: You might post this in one of the Adafruit forums or contact their customer support folks

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion. I am contacting them. I will post here if I find the answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt : I am using Dupont connector similar to this one.

https://www.gmelectronic.com/data/product/1024_1024/pctdetail.775-401.1.jpg

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to cut the connector off and crimp on one you selected yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a JST SM connector to me.

https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/JSTSM.pdf

Comment: Yes, and page 3 of the [translated datasheet for the sensor](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/828/C898+datasheet.pdf) on the Adafruit product page, also shows a JST connector.